# how to get created date of a .txt file using sql server?

Tags: sql-server

How to get a .txt file created datetime, and/or modified datetime using sql server.
ex:- "c:\Files\Info.txt" if i give this path i have to get created date and/or modified date using sql server.

Regards
Ram.

Comment: There are options to get the date using SQL Server but they are not very secure. I wouldn't recommend using SQL Server for this if you got other options.

Comment: I agree with Jody, learn a IDE and use it to build .txt file with data from SQL Server.